# NodeJS Express Express-session tenga o no tenga auth accede a rutas protegidas

Tags: nodejs, express, express-session

Estoy intentando trabajar con `express-session` y me acostumbro a **modularizar** codigo con fin de reutilizarlo.

Entonces dicho esto, sigo, Para usar las sessiones me he creado un `Routing` que empiece con `localhost.../auth/` para que todo lo que lleve en la **ruta** la palabra `auth` pase por el `middleware` de **autentificacion de sesion**.

Este seria mi codigo **auth.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
//session
const session = require('express-session');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');





//sesiones
router.use(cookieParser());
router.use(session({
    secret:'asdtGNKRfl-Fbyy',
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));




//middlewate
  //middleware session de comprobacion 
  const auth = function (req,res,next){
    if (req.session.id && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.send('No puedes acceder a esa pagina sin logearte')
    } else {
        next();
    } 
}




router.get('/',auth,(req,res)=>{
    console.log('INICIO ( / ) SESSION = ',req.session)
    res.send({
        'status':200,
        'message':'Bienvenido a tu cuenta !!!'
    })
})


//Crear session
router.get('/addSession',(req,res)=>{
    req.session.id = req.body.id;

    if (req.session.id) {
        res.send({
            status:200,
            message:'Has iniciado session correctamente'
        });
    }

})

//Quitar session

router.get('/logout',auth, function (req, res) {
    console.log('ON DESTROY SESSION = ',req.session.id)

    req.session.destroy();
    res.send("logout success!");
  });


module.exports = router;
```

En mi **app.js**

```
const authRoute = require('./src/routes/auth');
app.use('/auth',authRoute);
```

Decir tambien que estoy usando para las pruebas **Postman** . Expuesto lo que tengo prosigo con lo que estoy intentando.

Primero intento acceder a mi **ruta** `auth/` en la que no deberia pues si es mi primera vez que accedo me deberia mirar si tengo o no un `token` guardado mediante el `middleware` y en este momento no deberia de tener.

```
//middlewate
  //middleware session de comprobacion 
  const auth = function (req,res,next){
    if (req.session.id && req.cookies.user_sid) {
        res.send('No puedes acceder a esa pagina sin logearte')
    } else {
        next();
    } 
}
```

Pues la unica forma de 'inciar sesion' simulada es accediendo antes a esta ruta:

```
//Crear session
router.get('/addSession',(req,res)=>{
    req.session.id = req.body.id;

    if (req.session.id) {
        res.send({
            status:200,
            message:'Has iniciado session correctamente'
        });
    }

})
```

Por tanto para comprobar si todo esto funciona lleve a cabo esta **comprobacion**:

**Comprobacion**

- Primero accedo a la ruta `auth/` sin antes 'iniciar sesion'  en `auth/addSession` esto me deberia lanzar este error : `res.send('No puedes acceder a esa pagina sin logearte')`

  -Ahi se veria que **si** funciona, pero realmente lo que me hace es **acceder** a la ruta protegida mostrandome el mensaje `Has iniciado session correctamente` eso indica que **no funciona** como deberia

**Otra duda** es si este fragmento de codigo deberia de estar en `auth.js` o en `app.js`

```
//sesiones
router.use(cookieParser());
router.use(session({
    secret:'asdtGNKRfl-Fbyy',
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he **solucionado** no se si sera la mejor forma, me estaba equivocando a la hora de **comprobar** y **asignar** los valores de la `session` .
Sencillamente guarde en mi `req.session.user` un **nombre** para probar si lo almacenaba y comproba luego si existia y si lo hace.
A continuacion dejo el codigo arreglado :

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();







//middlewate
  //middleware session de comprobacion 
  const auth = function (req,res,next){
      console.log('SessionID (const auth) = '+req.sessionID)
    if (!req.session.user) {
        res.send('No puedes acceder a esa pagina sin logearte')

    } else {
        next();
    } 
}




router.get('/',auth,(req,res)=>{
    console.log('INICIO ( / ) SESSION = ',req.session)
    res.send({
        'status':200,
        'message':'Bienvenido a tu cuenta !!!',
        'usuario':req.session.user
    })
})


//Crear session
router.get('/addSession',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('SessionID = '+req.session.user)
    if (!req.session.user) {
        req.session.user = 'pepito';
        res.send({
            status:200,
            message:'Has iniciado session correctamente'
        });
    }
    else{
        res.send('Error! ya hay una session abierta')
    }
})

//Quitar session

router.get('/logout',auth, function (req, res) {
    console.log('ON DESTROY SESSION = ',req.session.id)

    req.session.destroy();
    res.send("logout success!");
  });


module.exports = router;
```

No obstante, lo publico como respuesta porque me ha funcionado, no quita que haya mil **respuestas mejores** en las que estaria encantado que le expusieran aqui. Espero haber podido ayudar a alguien